# How to leavy only numerical data in the file?

Tags: files-and-directories, text

Consider [a file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o0g7zstacci9ou/W-boson-13-TeV.lhe?dl=0). Apart from an information which is non-relevant for me, it contains blocks `<event></event>` with the numerical data inside. Is there a simple way to remove all the text except the data inside the `<event></event>` tags, i.e. to get a simple file with the numerical data only?

For example, the part of the file at which  blocks begin looks like

```
</init>
<event>
 3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
        2 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +1.5693915630e+02 1.5693915630e+02 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
       -1 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -1.0302107050e+01 1.0302107050e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
       24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +1.4663704925e+02 1.6724126335e+02 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
<mgrwt>
<rscale>  0 0.80419002E+02</rscale>
<asrwt>0</asrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="1">  1        2 0.24144484E-01 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="2">  1       -1 0.15849397E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
<totfact> 0.20046334E+05</totfact>
</mgrwt>
</event>
<event>
 3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
       -3 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +2.5673118905e+01 2.5673118905e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
        4 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -6.2976531778e+01 6.2976531778e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
       24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -3.7303412873e+01 8.8649650684e+01 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
<mgrwt>
<rscale>  0 0.80419002E+02</rscale>
<asrwt>0</asrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="1">  1        4 0.96886972E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="2">  1       -3 0.39497106E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
<totfact> 0.43040333E+04</totfact>
</mgrwt>
</event>
<event>
```

I would like to obtain just

```
 3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
        2 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +1.5693915630e+02 1.5693915630e+02 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
       -1 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -1.0302107050e+01 1.0302107050e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
       24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +1.4663704925e+02 1.6724126335e+02 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
 3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
       -3 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +2.5673118905e+01 2.5673118905e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
        4 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -6.2976531778e+01 6.2976531778e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
       24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 -3.7303412873e+01 8.8649650684e+01 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what an ideal output would look like.  I downloaded the file and it is not entirely clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @kickert : I apologize for such an unclear question, and just have added the relevant information.

Comment: So everything would be between `<event>` and`<mgrwt>`?

Comment: @kickert : to be precise, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import your data as a long string:

```
data = Import["D:\\documents\\Downloads\\W-boson-13-TeV.lhe", "String"]
```

Then use `StringCases` to extract what is between the tags `<event>` and `<mgrwt>`.

```
datablocks = StringCases[data2, "<event>" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "<mgrwt>" -> x]
```

If you want to turn this `String` data into numerical data, you can use the following:

```
numbers = 
 DeleteCases[
    ToExpression[
     StringSplit[StringSplit[StringReplace[#, "e" -> "E"], "\n"], 
      " "]], Null, {2}] & /@ datablocks
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any simple way to convert the obtained set into the ordinary numerical table immediately after applying the second command? The only way I have in mind is to first export it and then to import it as a table and remove empty elements.

Comment: @JohnTaylor 
Is this what you are looking for? 
`datablocks = 
 StringCases[data2, "<event>" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "<mgrwt>" -> x]` Then run 

`splits = DeleteCases[StringSplit[StringSplit[#, "\n"], " "], "", {2}]&/@datablocks`

Comment: No, I just want to work with the imported file as with the numerical data, just something like ToExpression[] but working in a correct manner.

Comment: @JohnTaylor What about this: `splits2 = 
 DeleteCases[
    ToExpression[
     StringSplit[StringSplit[StringReplace[#, "e" -> "E"], "\n"], 
      " "]], Null, {2}] & /@ datablocks`

Comment: This can be done cleaner using `XML` import.

Answer (score 3):

You have XML here. Why not use that fact?

```
xmlData = ImportString["<container>
 <event>
  3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
         2 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 \
+1.5693915630e+02 1.5693915630e+02 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
        -1 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 \
-1.0302107050e+01 1.0302107050e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
        24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 \
+1.4663704925e+02 1.6724126335e+02 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
 <mgrwt>
 <rscale>  0 0.80419002E+02</rscale>
 <asrwt>0</asrwt>
 <pdfrwt beam=\"1\">  1        2 0.24144484E-01 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
 <pdfrwt beam=\"2\">  1       -1 0.15849397E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
 <totfact> 0.20046334E+05</totfact>
 </mgrwt>
 </event>
 <event>
  3      1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01
        -3 -1    0    0    0  501 -0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 \
+2.5673118905e+01 2.5673118905e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
         4 -1    0    0  501    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 \
-6.2976531778e+01 6.2976531778e+01 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
        24  1    1    2    0    0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 \
-3.7303412873e+01 8.8649650684e+01 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
 <mgrwt>
 <rscale>  0 0.80419002E+02</rscale>
 <asrwt>0</asrwt>
 <pdfrwt beam=\"1\">  1        4 0.96886972E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
 <pdfrwt beam=\"2\">  1       -3 0.39497106E-02 0.80419002E+02</pdfrwt>
 <totfact> 0.43040333E+04</totfact>
 </mgrwt>
 </event>
 </container>",
 {"XML"}
 ];
```

Then you can use the nice XML structure to your advantage:

```
Cases[xmlData, XMLElement["event", _, {s_String, ___}] :> s, Infinity] // 
 StringRiffle[#, "\n"] &

"3 1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01 2 -1 0 0 501 \
0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +1.5693915630e+02 1.5693915630e+02 \
0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00 -1 -1 0 0 0 501 -0.0000000000e+00 \
-0.0000000000e+00 -1.0302107050e+01 1.0302107050e+01 0.0000000000e+00 \
0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 24 1 1 2 0 0 +0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 \
+1.4663704925e+02 1.6724126335e+02 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00
3 1 +8.3561000e+04 8.04190000e+01 7.54677100e-03 1.32786700e-01 -3 -1 0 0 0 \
501 -0.0000000000e+00 +0.0000000000e+00 +2.5673118905e+01 2.5673118905e+01 \
0.0000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 4 -1 0 0 501 0 +0.0000000000e+00 \
-0.0000000000e+00 -6.2976531778e+01 6.2976531778e+01 0.0000000000e+00 \
0.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00 24 1 1 2 0 0 +0.0000000000e+00 -0.0000000000e+00 \
-3.7303412873e+01 8.8649650684e+01 8.0419002446e+01 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input file is called "in.txt" the following expression, which writes a file called "out.txt" might suit you:

```
Export["out.txt", StringCases[Import["in.txt", "String"], Shortest["<event>\n" ~~ blk__ ~~ "\n<mgrwt>"] :> blk]]
```

Comment: beat me to it.  Slight differences in the code, but basically the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using the excerpt from the file shown in the question.

```
f = Import["test.txt", "String"];
data = StringCases[f, 
   RegularExpression["(?s)<event>(.+?)<mgrwt>"] -> "$1"];
data2 = ToExpression[StringSplit[StringReplace[data, "e" -> "*10^"]]]
```

> {{3,1,83561.,80.419,0.00754677,0.132787,2,-1,0,0,501,0,0.,0.,156.939,156.939,0.,0.,-1.,-1,-1,0,0,0,501,0.,0.,-10.3021,10.3021,0.,0.,1.,24,1,1,2,0,0,0.,0.,146.637,167.241,80.419,0.,-1.},{3,1,83561.,80.419,0.00754677,0.132787,-3,-1,0,0,0,501,0.,0.,25.6731,25.6731,0.,0.,1.,4,-1,0,0,501,0,0.,0.,-62.9765,62.9765,0.,0.,-1.,24,1,1,2,0,0,0.,0.,-37.3034,88.6497,80.419,0.,1.}}